# How to cancel AlarmManager using PendingIntents in different classes?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am trying to use AlarmManager for doing some tasks upon an alarm time I set.
I know that I have to use same PendingIntent to make and cancel alarm.
But, the problem is that I am making the alarm in class "ClassA" and cancelling the alarm in class "ClassB" later on.

That's why I wonder if the intents to be broadcast in each class are same or not since they use "different contexts" as they are in different classes, I guess.

Can they be considered as same PendingIntent and Can I cancel the alarm?
If not, how can I make them same?

For making an alarm in class "ClassA" (that extends BroadcastReceiver):

```
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, myReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, codeNum, intent, 0);
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pender);
```

For cancelling the alarm in class "ClassB" (that extends BaseAdapter):

```
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, myReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pilocal = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, codeNum, intent, 0);
pilocal.cancel();
alarm.cancel(pilocal);
```

Comment: PendingIntent implements Parcelable, so you could pass it around between activities. Have you tried to do it?

Comment: @Abdullah I can't pass it since the two classes are not related and they are independent of time. That's why I am trying to declare new Intent and PendingIntent using same reqeust code.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the same kind of PendingIntent by providing same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components, and same flags. 
Yes, you can cancel your alarm from another class if its still valid. Just make sure you pass the same parameters used, request code used to create the pending intent.

Comment: Your question is: Can they be considered as same PendingIntent and Can I cancel the alarm? If not, how can I make them same?

Yes, they can be considered as same PendingIntent and yes you can cancel the alarm from another class if that pending intent its still valid.

Comment: You mean they can be "same" PendingIntents even if they are using different contexts in Intent? Because you said it has to be same Intent, however, it's not same Intent action because the contexts in each Intent are different, I guess.

Comment: I have one more question. If I put extra string in intent when I create Alarm, do I also have to put extra string(although it's unnecessary) in Intent when cancelling alarm to make them same PendingIntent?

Comment: No. "extras" are ignored when comparing `Intent`s for this purpose. To cancel the alarm, you don't need any "extras".